# console log an input value for testing

Tags: javascript

so i am trying to make a simple calculator with 2 inputs then it concatenate them or divide ....

so first i want to check if the input value is in there

why won't this work ? 
i am learning the basics of js so i don't want to use any library

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('d1').value);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="d1">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there's nothing obviously the matter with it, the code works. Your textbox is initially blank, so it's not surprising that it doesn't log anything - there's nothing to log. What were you expecting instead? If, for example, you change your HTML to `<input type="number" id="d1" value="3">` then it will log `3` in the console.

Comment: When I run that code is successfully logs an empty string, which is what the value is.

Comment: when i insert a number in the text log is there any way to live log it

Comment: yes you can handle the "keyup" event, for example, it will run everytime the user types a character in the box. I think if you search for examples of this online you'll probably find plenty of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By directly using `console.log` it’s logging the value when the page is loaded. As the input field is blank, it’s displaying nothing. Instead, you need an event handler that runs every time you add something to the input field. Check the below code.

```js
document.getElementById("d1").addEventListener("input", () => console.log(document.getElementById("d1").value));
```

```html
<input id="d1" type="number">
```